# IMO 2011 Problem #6

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

After a few internet searches for really hard IMO #6 problems, I found the 2011 IMO #6 problem, which states:

"Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with circumcircle $\Gamma$. Let $\ell$ be a tangent line to $\Gamma$, and let $\ell_a, \ell_b$ and $\ell_c$ be the lines obtained by reflecting $\ell$ in the lines $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$, respectively. Show that the circumcircle of the triangle determined by the lines $\ell_a, \ell_b$ and $\ell_c$ is tangent to the circle $\Gamma$."

I didn't set out to solve it, but I was intrigued by it, so I opened up Geogebra and started constructing it. Fairly easy constructions led me to see a visual of it, which was great. But then I wondered, "why is one of the assumptions the fact that the starting triangle is acute?" So I moved my initial triangle points around so that the starting triangle is obtuse, acute, right, scalene, isosceles, equilateral...basically everything. The only thing I noticed was that an initial right triangle led to the second circumcircle to be degenerate (just a straight line, although it was still tangent to the first circumcircle). All other triangles led to the second circumcircle being tangent. So...why is that in the initial assumptions? Did I miss something (perhaps a special case)?

Also, I was asked by some students of mine, "who would think of this?" Did the problem's proposer have an idea that this construction would lead to a tangent circle? Was there a deeper question they were investigating that led them to these constructions?

Comment: Re the last paragraph: Posing a problem often starts with a simple and completely different observation, which is then diguised until it is no longer obvious ... I don't know what they might have started from here, though.

Comment: They add the condition of the triangle being acute to reduce the number of cases for the students giving synthetic geometry solutions. Depending on the relative positions of the elements in the figure equalities of angles and lengths can involve a sum in one case or a difference in another. It can become a tedious repetition. Since the acute case is already interesting enough, there is no need to make them waste time with the general case.

Comment: See how even in the [proposed solution(s)](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2011SL.pdf#page=61), even in the acute case, they use oriented angles to not have to repeat the arguments for many cases.